# Подскажите, как загрузить скаченную модель VGG16 в нейросетку

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

До сегодняшнего дня подгружал предобученную модель VGG16 следующей командой:

```py
vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(512, 512, 3))
```

Как и требуется [vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5) великолепно подкачивался с гитхаба. При вызове переменной `vgg16`, как и ожидалось, получал:

```py
<keras.engine.training.Model at 0x7f02bc635b00>
```

Тем не менее встала необходимость единоразово загрузить файл на компьютер и также грузить его в переменную `vgg16`. Из возможных решений посоветовали это:

```py
import h5py
f = 'vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'
vgg16 = h5py.File(f)
```

Однако при вызове переменной `vgg16`, в данной ситуации, получаем следующее:

```py
<HDF5 file "vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5" (mode r+)>
```

Не могу понять что я делаю не так. Подскажите советом, как именно мне добиться того же результата, как и при использовании функции `VGG16()`, описанной в самом начале? Как правильно загрузить в переменную скаченную модель?

Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Никакие **h5py** не нужны. В документации к [Керас](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16) прописано, что веса можно подгружать, [скачав их](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5) на компьютер и указав путь в аргументе **weights**. В данной ситуации команда выглядела бы следующим образом:

```py
vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5', input_shape=(512, 512, 3))
```

Если это не поможет, хотя я пробовал и все работало, то можно попробовать то, что посоветовали [ТУТ](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/issues/33#issuecomment-362174585). Метод более грязный, но также действенный.